# Magento: Discount Issue With Paypal

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, paypal-express, magento-1.9.1.1

I am applying discount on cart by following the link

http://pradeepkumarrcs.blogspot.in/2011/12/applying-custom-discount-amount-in.html

discount apply on cart but my problem is that when i checkout using paypal it redirects back me to cart and print the following error

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts (#10413: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details).

When i go through the log i found the following message

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'PayPal NVP gateway errors: Array Correlation ID: b1fffcad18843. Version: 72.0.'

Any help?